# Preventing jQuery counter from exceeding number of list items

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to figure out how to limit a jQuery counter dynamically from exceeding the number of items in a list.

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="mobile-nav">
            <div class="left-platform-arrow"></div>  
            <div class="counter">
                <span class="number">1</span>
                <span>/</span>
                <span class="label">1</span> 
            </div>    
            <div class="right-platform-arrow"></div>     
        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.right-platform-arrow').on('click', function(){
    $('.left li.selected').next().addClass('selected');
    $('.left li.selected').prev().removeClass('selected');
    $('.main .right .pane-open').next().addClass('pane-open');
    $('.main .right .pane-open').prev().removeClass('pane-open');       
    $('.number').text(function(i, t) {
        return Number(t) + 1;
    });
}); 
$('.left-platform-arrow').on('click', function(){
    $('.left li.selected').prev().addClass('selected');
    $('.left li.selected').next().removeClass('selected');
    $('.main .right .pane-open').prev().addClass('pane-open');
    $('.main .right .pane-open').next().removeClass('pane-open');
    $('.number').text(function(i, t) {
        return Number(t) - 1;
    });
}); 
$(".left .label").text(function() {
    return $(this).closest(".left").find("li").length;
});
```

You can see the current code live at http://clearleap.com/platform/the-clearleap-platform/clearplay/ (it only displays on mobile devices, so view from your cell phone).

The issue is that if you keep clicking the left or right arrow, the number will exceed the maximum number of items. For example, you can make it display 77/5 which is a rather annoying glitch.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Count the list items initially and place that into a variable. Then for every click test that you have not exceeded that amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are doing a ul li list then you could count the max by finding occurence of the ul's children by using

```
$('ul').children().length;
```

I have implemented a jsfiddle where this would work here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LKTQT/2/

I have made it so that every time the right button is pressed the value is parsed so that it is recognised as an integer. Then there is an if which makes sure that this value does not exceed the maximum number of children in the list.

(I've just replaced the jsfiddle with a second version which includes a left button example because I noticed that on your site it also allows you to go into negative values).

Comment: I have tried to apply your code to my page but I am still getting the issue with it counting forever.

Comment: It seems like "var maxListItems = $('.left ul').children().length;" is not returning a value for some reason. If I hard code a value (which I do not want to do), the code functions well.

Comment: Could you post the code where the list is implemented please?

Comment: I had a look at the code on your website and I've noticed your doing var maxListItems = $(".left").find("li").length;   Try switching that for $(".left").find("ul").length;

Comment: Hey. I have tried that too, I was trying a lot of tweaks last night. When its set to UL length, it still allows the counter up to 5 items even on pages with only 2 items. Its extremely odd.

Comment: I think i've found your problem. Looking through your code you have multiple divs with the class left and most of them have lists as children, so when your counting the amount of children for the ul in the left class you're counting these other ones as well.

Comment: I have renamed the div, from .left to .left-platform-nav which is a unique ID, and it still does not work

Comment: Have you tried this :  $('.left-platform-nav').find('li').length  or
$('.left-platform-nav ul').children().length